# Не работает скрипт на плавную анимацию

Tags: javascript, html

Привет вставил в HTML 2 скрипта: один для закрепления меню а второй для плавного перемещения по якорной странице второй почему то не работает и после нажатия на одну из кнопок меню ничего не происходит но когда убираю его то всё как бы работает только нет плавного перемещения. Вот оба скрипты (в навигации айди стоит правильно, помогите пжлст-а)

```
                <!--Закрепить окно сверху-->
<script>
    var h_hght = 110; // высота шапки
    var h_mrg = 0;    // отступ когда шапка уже не видна

    $(function(){

    var elem = $('#top_nav');
    var top = $(this).scrollTop();

    if(top > h_hght){
        elem.css('top', h_mrg);
    }           

    $(window).scroll(function(){
        top = $(this).scrollTop();

        if (top+h_mrg < h_hght) {
            elem.css('top', (h_hght-top));
        } else {
            elem.css('top', h_mrg);
        }
    });

});
</script>           
                <!--Плавный скролл-->
<script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#top_nav").on("click","a", function (event) {
        //отменяем стандартную обработку нажатия по ссылке
        event.preventDefault();

        //забираем идентификатор бока с атрибута href
        var id  = $(this).attr('href'),

        //узнаем высоту от начала страницы до блока на который ссылается якорь
            top = $(id).offset().top;

        //анимируем переход на расстояние - top за 1500 мс
        $('body,html').animate({scrollTop: top}, 500);
    });
});
      </script>
```

Comment: Приведите в вопросе элемент "#top_nav" с содержимым

Comment: В консольке ошибки есть?

Answer (score 0):

Ваш пример работает. По сему вопрос - jQuery подключили?

```js
$("#top_nav").on("click", "a", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var id = $(this).attr('href'),
    top = $(id).offset().top;
  $('body,html').animate({
    scrollTop: top
  }, 500);
});
```

```css
#qwe {
  position: absolute;
  top: 1000px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="top_nav">
  <a href="#qwe">to qwe</a>
</div>
<div id="qwe">qwe</div>
```